# heroku fatal error

Tags: git, heroku, cloud, push

I follow this tutrial for creating an facebook app on heroku cloud: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook but when i type $ git push heroku (the final step) I got: `fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repositoy`

???? why i got this... on tutorial I must get:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done,  etc.
```

also on preveous step when I must got:

```
$ git commit -am "changed greeting"
[master 0ff313a] changed greeting
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(- on screen . I got this:
```

lib/public/icon . etc
create mode 100644 .etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you don't have a remote git repository associated with your local repository. Try the command:

```
git remote -v show
```

If you don't have an entry that looks something like

```
heroku git@heroku.com:name-of-your-app.git (push)
```

where name-of-your-app is the name of your Heroku hosted application, then you need to add a remote git repository with

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:name-of-your-app.git
```

again with name-of-your-app being the name of your Heroku app.